# What amount of protein comprises the feces of a domestic cat?

Tags: literature, gastroenterology, feline

I've heard it said that the fecal excrement of cats, *Felis catus*, contains adequate amounts of protein so as to attract the interest of other animals e.g. dogs (*Canis familiaris*).

However, I am unable to locate any studies which reported the composition of a cat's feces as compared to those of any other animal with regards to a controlled quantity of proteins in the diet.  I do see a lot of people on the internet making claims one way or the other, but never a citation to be seen.

Would anyone be interested in citing some references here so as to provide a more reputable resolution to this oft–repeated “fact”?
Unlikely as that would be, I'll post an answer here next time I check the university library.